# Detecting Windows 10 "Focus Mode" in Javascript for HTML 5 notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-10, html5-notifications

As of today, HTML 5 notifications in Chrome go through the Windows 10 action center, with native Windows notifications.

Previously, I had notifications pop up, and disappear after a few seconds.

However, if a user is in Window's "focus mode", they would never see these notifications.

I'm thinking it's most likely not possible, but is there a way I can detect when the user is in Windows' "Focus Mode"? In this case, I would like to not dismiss the notification automatically until after they exit "Focus Mode".

Also, is there a way to indicate that the notificiation is "important"?